# Wi-Fi on a network with SSID Broadcast disabled

Tags: raspbian, wireless

I bought a new Raspberry Pi B+ and a Wi-Pi Wireless Adapter.
The Wi-Pi appears to be a Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter.

I am can get the Wi-Pi running on a network with `SSID` Broadcast enabled.
How do I get it working on a network with `SSID` Broadcast disabled? All the other devices on the network (Macs, Windows, and an assortment of iDevices) work OK.

Currently I have `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual

wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

and `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="SSID"
    psk="PSK"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
    eap=MD5
}
```

"SSID" & "PSK" replace the actual values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.
Include `scan_ssid=1` in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

This is listed in examples in `man wpa_supplicant.conf` although no explanation is given of what the function is.